# How to tell Deployer to use different PHP version once ssh'ed to my shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, php-deployer

I'm experimenting with Deployer to deploy Laravel application into shared hosting (using laravel recipe) from my local `~/Code/project_foo`.

The point is that when I'm connected to my shared hosting server via `ssh`, then default `php -v` version is `5.6.33`. I confirmed that I can change php version on fly by calling `php70 -v` or even whole path like `/usr/local/bin/php70 whatever`.

The point is that I don't know how to tell deployer to call commands using `php70` which is required, otherwise `composer install` fails.

[image]

So in Terminal I'm inside root of the Laravel project and I simply call:

`dep deploy`

My `deploy.php` is messy and very simple but this is just a proof of concept. I'm trying to figure out everything and then I will make it look nicer.

[image]

I checked the [source code of the laravel recipe](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/recipe/laravel.php), and I saw that there is:

`{{bin/php}}`

but I don't know how to override the value to match what my hosting tells me to use:

`/usr/local/bin/php70`

Please, give me any hints how to force the script use different PHP version once connected to the remote host / server.

This is whole script:

```
<?php
namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/laravel.php';


//env('bin/php', '/usr/local/bin/php70'); // <- I thought that this will work but it doesn't change anything


// Project name
set('application', 'my_project');

// Project repository
set('repository', 'git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git');

// [Optional] Allocate tty for git clone. Default value is false.
set('git_tty', true); 

// Shared files/dirs between deploys 
add('shared_files', []);
add('shared_dirs', []);

// Writable dirs by web server 
add('writable_dirs', []);


// Hosts

host('xxx')
    ->user('xxx')
    ->set('deploy_path', '/home/slickpl/projects/xxx');

// Tasks

task('build', function () {
    run('cd {{release_path}} && build');
});

// [Optional] if deploy fails automatically unlock.
after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');

// Migrate database before symlink new release.

before('deploy:symlink', 'artisan:migrate');
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution.

I added (after `require`):

```
set('bin/php', function () {
    return '/usr/local/bin/php70';
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt, what do you mean `after require` - I am having the same issue I tried to set php path right after the `require 'recipe/laravel.php'` (not sure if that is what you mean by require) wihout any luck. `set('bin/php', function () { return '/var/www/my-user/data/bin/php';})`

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Put it after the 4th line (`require 'recipe/laravel.php';`).

Comment: This was working but the problem wasn't in the config but the shell ouput for example my task `php_ver` outputs 5.6 on the other hand the deployer script is using the correct php version (7.3) - not sure why ( logging in as the user itself as well..) Anyways thanks for the reply Matt. Cheers.

Answer (score 13):

For anybody who searches for changing Composer's PHP version:

```php
set('bin/composer', function () {
    return '/usr/bin/php7.4 /usr/local/bin/composer';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is function `locateBinaryPath()`
so result is:

```php
set('bin/php', function () {
    return locateBinaryPath('php7.4');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**first found php path and composer path  use this**
for more information [Setting PHP versions in Deployer deployments](https://mklasen.com/setting-php-versions-in-deployer-deployments/)

```
find / -type f -name "php"   2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"

find / -type f -name "composer"   2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

then

```
set('bin/composer',
function () {
    return 'php_path composer_path';
});
```

like this

```
set('bin/composer',
function () {
    return '/opt/remi/php73/root/usr/bin/php /usr/bin/composer';
});
```